# SQL Injection in a Disguise

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

Sometimes SQL Inject queries may come in a disguise by using a different character set that you are used to. But even in those disguise modes, the query string would still include familiar words such as union and cast and varchar etc..

My question is this;

Is it possible to even disguise those words too? In other words, could "union" or "cast" be disguised as well?

Comment: This issue would be absolutely, completely moot if you simply used parameterized queries.

Comment: @Andrew: too true, though it might be useful to know when setting up a honeypot.

Comment: @sarnold: presumably if you are going so far as to bait hackers then you probably have some clue as to what you are doing.

Comment: @AndrewBarber ..and you have benign aspirations.

Comment: Why do you ask this? Do you plan to create an SQL-injection attacking device? Or an anti-SQL-injection-attack identifier/defender?

Comment: @paislee Well, that's better than *malignant aspirations*... though I suspect you meant something slightly different.

Comment: Disguise from whom? URL encoding would hide them from the user. Since the database server has to process SQL as clear ("undisguised") text at /some/ point, hiding them from the server code would be more difficult. (Also, if you're trying to prevent SQL injection, trying to compose an exhaustive list of things to look for is probably a bad approach.)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Query parameters are great and important to use. But they don't account for every case of writing dynamic SQL. For example, you can't use a parameter for a table name, a column name, an SQL keyword, an expression, or a list of values. So we do use parameters, but we need other techniques too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SQL standard requires that keywords use Latin characters A through Z or a through z, digits 0 through 9, and specific special characters.  See [SQL Language Elements](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/sql-language-elements) in "SQL-99 Complete, Really".

That said, individual implementations (e.g. Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL) may not conform to the standard perfectly.  The best way to be sure is to test the brand and version of RDBMS you use.

---

Re your comments:  MySQL allows `/* */` comments to be embedded within keywords, but in other brands of databases, an inline comment is more or less like whitespace.
So `SEL/* */ECT` is like `SEL ECT` which of course is not a valid keyword so it would fail.

I assume that comment delimiters must also be characters in the ascii range, but I have not tested this to be sure.  And it could vary by brand of RDBMS depending on implementation.  So the answer must take that into account (hint: you haven't told us what brand of database you're using).

Another type of "disguise" could be URL encoding.  That is, using HTML entities or HTML hex-encoding for individual characters.  SQL won't recognize these, but if you filter raw inputs before decoding, something could slip past your checks.

Ultimately, my policy for the best practice is:

- Never let user input be run as code (this also applies to any untrusted content read from a file or even from the database itself).  Use parameterization or at least a dependable escaping function instead of interpolating content directly into SQL strings.
- Parameterization doesn't help if you want to make other parts of your SQL dynamic based on user input.  For instance, letting the user choose how to sort their result:

  ```
    SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY $ColumnOfUsersChoice $AscVsDesc
  ```

In that case my practice is to use **whitelisting**, so we compare the user input against a fixed set of valid choices, instead of trying to use pattern-matching with regular expressions.  The advantage of whitelisting is that if a malicious user tries anything clever, their input will simply be ignored.

For examples of whitelisting, see my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) or my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Here's a video recording of me presenting the SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies talk: http://marakana.com/forums/web_dev/general/210.html  But I continue to improve the slides since that video was made, so there will be some differences.

Comment: got it, got it Bill. I will pay attention to accepting answers...  I did not know about that I have to accept answers. Now that I know, I won't be skipping on that. Though, some people saw it necessary that this thread should be closed, I will add my comments and what I've learned from this anyway just to make sure that my understanding is correct.

Comment: I take your answer as NO. So as an example, it's not possible to do a cast without actually using the word CAST. 

But on the other hand, knowing this does not help. Cause I believe there is a way to write CAST or SELECT by using / * * / ( sql comments ) and thus disguising the word CAST as something like C/**/AST. Please verify.  Just curious... I have seen some people do that. Ofcourse, one could first take / * and * / out from the org. query (by replace) and then check if it contains the word CAST or not.. But that would bring the next question if /* and */ could be coming in disquise too.

Comment: From here, I understand that seeking for certain words, that are in some sort of black list is a bad way to look at things.. As GUFFA below suspected it correctly. He did see the purpose of the question. And MIKE SAMUEL's very interesting snippet also proves that you don't even need A-z to cause havoc. Wow! Excellent snippet, an eye opener...  Thank you all for nailing this for me. you all deserve an ACCEPT. But I guess I can only pick one... So I will go with the direct answer to my question which also came first so that is you... But I benefited a lot from Mike's reply as well...

Comment: @John *Just use parameterized queries*; problem solved.

Comment: @Bill, great reply.. it's interesting; I had seen that presentation last week or so but I got lost in it therefore, I clicked away half way down the road - without fullt benefiting from it. No doubt, it's a great resource, is there anyway I can obtain an mp3 version of it? One can still learn a lot from just listening the presentation.

Comment: @Bill, what I have learned from previous readings mysql_real_escape_string is simply a joke and there are ways to bypass that thanks to the deployment of various char sets such as GBK, the multibyte ones.. It looks like mysql_real_escape_string protects you 99 out of 100 cases but as long as that 1 way is out in the open, the database is still vulnerable and therefore, it's a matter of time to get hacked. And the only way to prevent the injection is to use parameterized statements and lots of filtering/validating using whitelists. Is this conclusion of "never use mysql_real_escape!" correct?

Comment: @JohnSmith: No, it's safe to use mysql_real_escape_string if you use a charset other than gbk or sjis.  Just set the connection character set to utf8, which is a better choice for modern multibyte support anyway.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Here's a video of me presenting the SQL Injection talk at the San Francisco MySQL Meetup:  http://marakana.com/forums/web_dev/general/210.html

Comment: @Bill, that issue of working within utf-8 is the key. Cause mysql_real_esc totally relies on that. If you miss it, the whole thing becomes vulnerable.   
Yesterday, I had to initiate [another stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073717/php-detecting-the-user-supplied-characters-char-set) specifically about utf-8 and making sure I work within utf-8. But still just do not know how to reliably make it happen.

Practically speaking, in PHP, is it possible to detect if a user_input is or is not sent in utf-8?  I will continue in the next comment.

Comment: continue.... To make sure, my PHP environment is set to work within utf-8 and utf-8 only, does the following checks enough or is there still a hole somewhere that a non-utf-8 ( a GBK for example ) can still slip in to render mysql_real_escape_string useless?

Here is what I got so far.

[in php.ini] default_charset = "utf-8"
[in php] check mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true); 
[in php] do mysql_query(SET NAMES utf8); 
[in php] do header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8'); 
Is that enough? When/How do I know if mysql_real_escape is the right fit for the userstring at hand!

Comment: @Bill, BTW! many thanks for the video link.. i sure will watch it which will probably load me up with better questions & insight into the matter.

Comment: @JohnSmith:  I'm not a charset expert, here's where my knowledge falls short.  But I assume if a client sends GBK and you try to process it with MySQL's charset set to utf8 the worst that will happen is that you'll get garbage.

Comment: @Bill: I watched your [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4dJ7hdA8fs) on SQL Injection, a couple of times already. Best talk I've ever seen on this particular subject. an eye opener... Do you have any other links leading to other security/programming talks you've been involved?

Comment: @JohnSmith, I post my slides on http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin when I can.  Not many of my talks have been recorded, but check out http://www.percona.tv/?s=karwin

Answer (score 5):

SQL injection does not need to include any keywords.

For example,

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID=<<<Injected Payload>>>
```

will do more than intended with an injected payload that contains no alphanumeric characters:

```
''||''=''
```

Answer (score 5):

You are approaching the problem from the wrong direction. The only reliable way to protect against SQL injection is to make sure that the data is never executed as code, by parsing it or escaping it correctly.

Using parameterised queries will help you with the escaping, as that is tricky to do correctly.

Looking for keywords in the input is only done as a secondary measure, to protect badly written code that is completely missing any protection.