# PHP - detecting the user supplied character's char set

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

Is it possible to detect the user's string's char set?

If not, how about the next question..

Are there *reliable* built-in PHP functions that can accurately tell if the user supplied string ( be it supplied thru get/post/cookie etc), are in a UTF-8 or not? In other words, can I do something like

is_utf8($_GET['first_name'])

Is there anyway this function could produce a TRUE where in reality the first_name was not in UTF-8?

Comment: Please upvote and accept answers to your previous questions (this one also). See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1:

You can give [`mb_detect_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_check_encoding) a try, but it's pretty much a shot in the dark. An "encoded" string is just a bunch of bytes. Such byte sequences are often equally valid in any number of different encodings. It's therefore by definition not possible to detect an unknown encoding **reliably**, you can only guess. For this reason there exist meta information such as HTTP headers which should communicate the encoding of the transferred content. Check those if available.

Regarding 2:

[`mb_check_encoding($var, 'UTF-8')`](http://php.net/mb_check_encoding) will tell you whether the string is a valid UTF-8 string. As far as I've seen, in recent versions of PHP it does what it says on the tin. That still doesn't mean the string is necessarily really a UTF-8 string, it just means the byte sequence is in an order that is valid in UTF-8.

Comment: how about assuming that the incoming string is in utf-8 and doing an decode on it? if the results match, can we safely conclude that the assumption was right that yes in deed it was encoded in utf-8?  So in PHP, if I do the following and it comes back as TRUE, would that be a good way to verify that it was UTF-8?                       if ($_GET['name'] == utf8_decode($_GET['name'])

Comment: Are we saying that there is nothing in the PHP world as we stand today to verify that a user input is in utf-8 or not?? How am I going to make sure that I can escape/sanitize things properly for the current user strig at hand? My escape/sanitization filters are all designed to deal with utf-8.

Comment: Text is just bytes, if you don't *know* which encoding these bytes represent pretty much all bets are off. If you don't understand why this is, I recommend you read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/). That's not just a PHP thing, it's a general issue regarding how text is represented by computers.